# React useEffect reRenders Infinitely if functional dependencyies are added

Tags: react-hooks, infinite-loop, use-effect, functional-dependencies

I am using react useEffect hook for getting Data from Backend.
And I am using two functions(props de-structured)

1. createError(if there is any error)
2. setisLoading (Loading spinner on data fetching)
   code is :

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     const fetchCourses = async () => {
>       setisLoading(true);
>
>       try {
>         const response = await fetch(
>           `${localurl}api/course/getEnglishCourses`,
>           {
>             method: "GET",
>             headers: {
>               "Content-Type": "application/json",
>             },
>           }
>         );
>
>         const responseData = await response.json();
>         setLoadCourses(responseData.courses);
>         setisLoading(false);
>         // console.log(responseData.courses);
>       } catch (err) {
>         setisLoading(false);
>         createError("Something Went Wrong");
>       }
>     };
>
>     fetchCourses();   }, []);
> ```

ESLint prompts "createError" and "setisLoading" are missing dependencies.

If I add these useEffect runs infinitely, as setisloading re-starts the useEffect call every time.

How to stop this from happening??

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing and just want to suppress the warning, you can add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` before your deps to run the effect only on first render.